# Avoid VS 2022 to add BackSlash when pasting double quote

Tags: visual-studio-2022, pasting

There is an unexpected behavior in Visual Studio 2022. When you paste text containing a single quote (e.g. `");` ) to a text line that already has a single double quote on it then Visual Studio will automatically add a backslash.

For example, if you have the code line:

```
string myVar = " Something
```

And if you want to paste `");` at the end of it, then it will produce:

```
string myVar= " Something  \");
```

And this will trigger a syntax error of course.

When pasting the same text (`");` ) to a line without a double quote on it then the paste works as expected:

```
string myVar = Something ");
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get the same in Visual Studio 17.7.3 - I assume that VS is trying to be smart and thinks that you are pasting inside a set of quotes and that escaping the double quote that you are pasting would be the right thing to do. Visual Studio also helpfully adds the closing double quote when you type the opening one, unless you have disabled that. Unfortunately I don't have an answer to solve your problem. You could try giving feedback to Microsoft if no solution is found.

Comment: Thank you Piers, your assumption is certainly right and this behavior start with version 17.*.*
Now it will be great that this "I'll try to be smarter than you" feature can be disabled :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you CTRL+V (paste), then CTRL+Z (undo) it removes the backslash.

I haven't figured out how to stop the behaviour, though, other than using a different text editor.